# Should I purchase and use a grease or oil splash screen?

Tags: frying, equipment, stove

I use a sauce pan often for grilling chicken or frying bacon, and a lot of grease tends to splash out. There are fine mesh screens available with a handle designed to cover the pan without creating a seal.

Are these a worthwhile investment, or do they just wind up being one more item to clean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are one more item to clean, but they are a lot easier to clean than the walls and stove.

I have several in different sizes - very worthwhile in my opinion.

Comment: So far I am making good use of one, and not finding it particularly difficult to clean.

Answer (score 2):

I recently bought one and use it, but its use is limited by the fact that you will have to take it off to flip or move the food in the pan.  Often this is when the splattering is most likely to occur. Still, it's better than not having one.